# multiresolution analysis scaling identity

Tags: functional-equations, signal-processing, wavelets

I'm reading the First Course in Wavelets with Fourier Analysis by Boggess & Narcowich. In chapter 5 section 1.2, it defines
$$\newcommand{\scal}[1]{\langle{#1}\rangle}p_k = \sqrt2 \scal{ \phi, \phi_{1,k} } = 2 \int \phi(x) \overline{\phi(2x-k)}\, dx$$ for a given scaling function $\phi$ so that $$\phi(x) = \sum_k p_k \phi(2x-k),$$ where the limit is presumably taken in $L^2$. And it states that $\sum_k p_k = 2$ in Theorem 5.9. I believe there is a missing assumption here. We do not know if $\sum_k p_k$ converges in the first place. The question now is, just exactly what would be the right assumption to make this work.

My best guess is to require the convergence of $\phi(x) = \sum_k p_k \phi(2x-k)$ in $L^1$. Is that sufficient? Any better suggestions? And what about the resulting convergence of $\sum_k p_k$? It seems to me that we only have conditional convergence here, but without absolute convergence, I am not sure if the proof of the subsequent statements, $\sum_k p_{2k}=1$ and $\sum_k p_{2k+1}=1$, would still work.

Comment: In the copy I have got ahold of there is a proof of the claim $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in Z} p_k = 2$ using theorem 5.6 integrating both sides w.r.t. x and a change of variable for the integral on the right hand side. Therefore convergence should not be a problem.

Comment: First of all, how do you know you can integrate it? Is it in $L^1$? There are functions that are in $L^2$ but not in $L^1$.

Comment: That is a fair point. I have never seen anyone try to construct an MRA that is not in $L^1$. I would fail to see the utility. In engineering to approximate things with a function that is not even integrable. Such things are usually considered theoretical curiosities. Most $\phi$ have compact support and all which I have ever seen are bounded in absolute value. This is enough to ensure them lying in $L^1$. I will point you to a proof that does not rely on integrability if I find one.

Comment: A few exceptions do exist. For example Shannon wavelets and some other wavelets specifically constructed by the Fourier transform. They are integrable but not in $L^1$.

Comment: The scaling function is sometimes normalized to have Fourier DC component of 1. i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)dt = 1$. This would be impossible if the integral did not exist.

Comment: Wait, that is all we need. If it has a Fourier transform then it's DC component (zero frequency) must exist. That DC component is the integral of the function.

Comment: That again only holds if the function is $L^1$. Otherwise the Fourier transform is in $L^2$ without values at specific points. That the Fourier transform is continuous at frequency zero, thus can be assigned a unique value there, is now an additional demand. @mathreadler

Comment: Hmm yes you are right @LutzLehmann. I don't think I have read any book on wavelets that does not specify that the Father wavelets $\phi$ have a mean in the integral sense (sometimes normalized to $1$) and that the Mother wavelets $\psi$ have a mean of $0$ in the same sense. I am surprised that this book does not seem to mention that at all.

Comment: Maybe we will simply need to specify that the integral exists as an extra condition for the MRA.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** The integral stated at the bottom of the proof must exist because $\phi$ would not be Fourier transformable otherwise since it's Fourier Transform at frequency 0 is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)\cdot e^{-2\pi n \cdot 0}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(t)dt$$

---

In the copy of the edition I have the proof goes as follows:

"**Theorem 5.9** Suppose $\{V_j;j\in Z\}$ is a multiresolution analysis with scaling function $\phi$. Then the following equalities hold:

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in Z} p_{k-2l} {\bar{p_k}
   } = 2\delta_{l0}$
2. $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in Z} |p_k|^2 = 2$
3. $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in Z} p_k = 2$
4. $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in Z} p_{2k} = 1$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k\in Z} p_{2k+1} = 1$

**Proof:** The first equation follows from the two-scale relation (Theorem 5.6) and the fact that $\{\phi(x-k), k\in Z\}$ is orthonormal. We leave the details to Exercise 4a. By setting $l=0$ in the first equation we get the second equation. The proof of the third equation uses Theorem 5.6 as follows:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx = \sum_{k\in Z} p_k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(2x-k)dx$$

By letting $t = 2x-k$ and $dx = dt/2$ we obtain:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)dx = 1/2\sum_{k\in Z} p_k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(t)dt$$

Now $\int\phi(t)dt$ cannot be zero (see Exercise 6) for otherwise we could never approximate functions $f\in L^2(R)$ with $\int f(t)dt \neq 0$ by functions in $V_j$. Therefore the factor $\int \phi(t)dt$ on the right can be cancelled with $\int \phi(x)dx$ on the left (cancelled as divided away, my remark). The third equation now follows."

The proof of 4 is a little lengthier but also seems sound.

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I'm objecting here. You really can't swap the order of the infinite sum against the integration here without some kind of justification, and I really think that the author glossed over this detail. Proof of the 4th statement is also broken, because it first relies on the third statement that has missing assumption, and on top of that it has another swap of order of summation. All these things require serious justification.